# Sharepoint List - The button inside the column does not work when searching

Tags: list, search, button

I created Sharepoint - List as a stock list. I have a button in the column that sends a request for an item and at the same time adds a reserved flag to the item.

Code here:

```
{
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent": "Odeslat Žádost",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"7347b7be-696f-46c8-bae8-78c230a354b3\"}"
  },
  "style": {
    "background-color": "#03A9F4",
    "color": "white",
    "visibility": {
      "operator": "?",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "==",
          "operands": [
            "[$Sloupec11]",
            ""
          ]
        },
        "visible",
        "hidden"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Screenshoot:
[image]

So far, everything works, but when you search for an item using the search bar, the button stops working.

[image]

Is my procedure bad? Thank you for your help.

Best Regards

Frantisek

**EDIT:**
OK, I understand there's a search error. For filtering, but the button works. Is there a way to create a search item using a filter?

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you have an additional question not related to the `executeFlow` action no longer working. Please open a separate question for that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format is correct. I can confirm I'm having the same issue. The Launch Flow action works just fine until I search the list. This is a bug that should be submitted here: https://aka.ms/spdev-issues

All other row actions execute, but not `executeFlow` - the flow panel never shows.